# How to give System property to my test via Gradle and -D

Tags: java, testing, gradle

I have a a Java program which reads a System property

```
System.getProperty("cassandra.ip");
```

and I have a Gradle build file that I start with

```
gradle test -Pcassandra.ip=192.168.33.13
```

or

```
gradle test -Dcassandra.ip=192.168.33.13
```

however **System.getProperty** will always return **null**.

The only way I found was to add that in my Gradle build file via

```
test {
    systemProperty "cassandra.ip", "192.168.33.13"
}
```

How Do I do it via -D

Comment: What happens when you use `gradle -Dcassandra.ip=192.168.33.13`? Anyway, the test task forks one or several new JVMs. So you'll have to pass properties explicitely. Nobody forces you to hardcode their value in the build, though.

Comment: Also take a look in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23689054/problems-passing-system-properties-and-parameters-when-running-java-class-via-gr/23689696#23689696

Answer (score 180, accepted):

The -P flag is for gradle properties, and the -D flag is for JVM properties. Because the test may be forked in a new JVM, the -D argument passed to gradle will not be propagated to the test - it sounds like that is the behavior you are seeing.

You can use the systemProperty in your `test` block as you have done but base it on the incoming gradle property by passing it with it -P:

```
test {
    systemProperty "cassandra.ip", project.getProperty("cassandra.ip")
}
```

or alternatively, if you are passing it in via -D

```
test {
    systemProperty "cassandra.ip", System.getProperty("cassandra.ip")
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me (tested using      `System.getProperties().stringPropertyNames().forEach(System.out::println);`
in the Java code, it doesn't appear)

Comment: Warning: `getProperty` throws `MissingPropertyException` if property is not found. Use Eron's answer instead: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43112126/915441

Comment: Adding default values to `gradle.properties` will prevent the `MissingPropertyException`.

Comment: I can get neither of these methods to work. Whatever I do myProperty is always null. This includes all of the methods mentioned below, too. I am wondering if this is something to do with a more recent version, as all comments are from 2018? @CLOVIS did you find a solution to this?

Comment: @HesterLyons I only wanted to know *if* the build was testing or normally running, so I used the property gradle itself adds when testing; you can see the code here: https://github.com/CLOVIS-AI/wildfyre-java/blob/master/src/main/java/net/wildfyre/http/Request.kt#L309

Answer (score 35):

Came across this very much problem, except i don't want to list all properties given on the commandline in the gradle script again. Therefore i send all system properties to my test

```
task integrationTest(type: Test) {
    useTestNG()
    options {
        systemProperties(System.getProperties())
    }
}
```

Comment: Be careful when doing this. It might easily break Gradle's up-to-date checks when system properties change during invocations.

Comment: Same for JavaExec tasks. The props were present in the task, but not in the java program, unless the were set again in the task.

Comment: Same problem as OP, adding `options` to test task helped:  `tasks.named('test') {... options {systemProperties(System.getProperties())}`

Answer (score 13):

I had a case where I needed to pass *multiple* system properties into the test JVM but not *all* (didn't want to pass in irrelevant ones). Based on the above answers, and by using `subMap` to filter the ones I needed, this worked for me:

```
task integrationTest(type: Test) {
    // ... Do stuff here ...
    systemProperties System.getProperties().subMap(['PROP1', 'PROP2'])
}
```

In this example, only `PROP1` and `PROP2` will be passed in, if they exist in gradle's JVM.

Answer (score 10):

Here's a variant that passes numerous project properties to the test JVM as system properties.  I prefer project properties over system properties to increase flexibility.

```
task intTest(type: Test) {
    systemProperties project.properties.subMap(["foo", "bar"])
}
```

Which may be passed on the command-line:

```
 $ gradle intTest -Pfoo=1 -Pbar=2
```

And retrieved in your test:

```
String foo = System.getProperty("foo");
```

Comment: When running `System.getProperty("someprop")` using that subMap method, I got  `{someprop=foo}` instead of `foo`. I had to use `systemProperty "foo", project.properties.subMap(["foo"]).get("foo")` in build.gradle

Comment: @YngvarKristiansen where (how) were you using `systemProperty "foo"`? i.e. I'm asking to see the full line of code where this was used? I'm trying everything suggested in this question and still Gradle is not passing any arguments. Hoping this might resolve!

Comment: @HesterLyons I'm sorry, I didn't keep my code, so I don't know anymore :\ I agree that it looks out of place.

Comment: Thank you @YngvarKristiansen. I have since worked out that my problem was being caused by the junit gradle plugin which was included in my gradle.build. Very odd.

Answer (score 2):

So I've stumbled on that issue today as well, and what worked for me was the following:

```
ext.env='prod'
test {
  systemProperty 'env', System.properties['env'] ?: "${env}"
  println "# test environment: " + systemProperties['env']
  ...
}
```

I'm calling my test task using *-Penv=dev* and I get my 'dev' value in my print, or 'prod' if I do not send any value, which is the expected behavior for me.

Value is also accessible on java side, using *System.getProperty("env")*.

My conclusion on the matter is that input value (parameter) is actually stored under *System*, making it accessible through either *System.properties['env']* or *System.getProperty("env")*, whereas output (system property) is stored in a *systemProperties* array, making it readable through *systemProperties['env']*.

Comment: Work for me. thanks.  in my case I was need to pass github token to tests by system properties.

Answer (score 2):

Here is something that worked for me

```
//in build.gradle file

    tasks.withType(Test) {
        systemProperties = [
           ip: System.getProperty('ip', '192.168.33.13'),
        ]
    }

    task integrationTests(type: Test){
        useTestNG()
    }
```

Suppose if you are using TestNG, you can add the annotation @Parameters as shown below

```
  public class IpAddress {
    @Test
    @Parameters("ip")
    public void printIpAddress(String ip) {
        System.out.println(ip);
    }
 }
```

Now you are good to execute a gradlew command

```
./gradlew clean -Dip="xx.xx.xx.xx" integrationTests --tests "IpAddress"
```

If you want to use @DataProvider to pass the test data, you can pass it like below and execute the same above gradle command to run the test

```
 public class IpAddress {
    @DataProvider(name = "GetIP")
    private static Object[][] getIp() {
        return new Object[][]{
                //if -Dip is not provided in command, then by default it gets the value assigned in build.gradle file i.e.'192.168.33.13'
                {System.getProperty("ip")}, 
        };
    }

    @Test(dataProvider = "GetIP")
    public void printIpAddress(String ip) {
        System.out.println(ip);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was need to pass github token to tests by system properties.

I have tried this:

```
systemProperty "github.token", System.getProperty("github.token")
```

But give me a error, so a passed a default value:

```
ext.github_token='TOKEN'
test {
    systemProperty 'github.token', System.properties['github.token'] ?: "${github_token}"
}
```