# Google Play Developer API version_name

Tags: android, gradle, google-play-developer-api

I'm trying to automate publishing an app to the Google Play store using the [Gradle Play Publisher](https://github.com/Triple-T/gradle-play-publisher). So far so good except that I haven't been able to update the `version_name` this way, it just ignores it.

I Tried `./gradlew publishRelease -Dversion_name=3.0.0`. It looks like it's due to Google Play API limitations. If I run `./gradlew assembleRelease -Dversion_name=3.0.0` to generate the apk and then upload the apk manually it correctly uploads with the version `3.0.0`. Just want to make sure is it not possible to upload the version name vía Google Play Developer API or is it an issue of *Gradle Play Publisher*?

> build.gradle

```
def version_name = System.getProperty("version_name")

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode version_code
        versionName "${version_name}"
        renderscriptTargetApi 23
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
        multiDexEnabled true

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

Following R. Zagórski suggestions I tried:

**1.**

`./gradlew assembleRelease -Dversion_name=3.0.0 publishRelease`

and

**2.**

`./gradlew assembleRelease -Pversion_name=3.0.0 publishRelease`

> build.gradle

```
def version_name = project.getProperty("version_name")
println "version name: "+version_name

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode version_code
        versionName "${version_name}"
        renderscriptTargetApi 23
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
        multiDexEnabled true

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    ...
}
```

But still nothing. Just to be clear the problem is not that I'm not getting the `version_name` or the wrong `version_name` in the build, in fact that `println` you see there prints the right version. Is just that I'm not getting anything at all in the Google play store (see image below).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is not the issue of plugin or API. This is just how `gradle` works. Other answers indicating the problem are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23689696/6507689) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21406600/6507689).

Basically the problem is that `gradle` might create a JVM fork processes to complete the tasks. Therefore, when running `publishRelease`, which [depends on 
`assembleRelease`](https://github.com/Triple-T/gradle-play-publisher/blob/master/src/main/groovy/de/triplet/gradle/play/PlayPublisherPlugin.groovy#L103), separate process might be created to finish assembling before publishing. And you pass system property to publish taksand not assemble task.

The solution might be to run two tasks simultaneously, passing argument to appropriate one:

```
./gradlew assembleRelease -Dversion_name=3.0.0 publishRelease
```

Or set project property instead of system property as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21406600/6507689)

Comment: tried that but nothing. I edited my question so you can see what I tried and tell me if I misunderstood something.

Comment: Gradle task must produce some logs and errors if happen.