# Grails 3.3.1 and passing system properties to test-app

Tags: grails, grails-3.3

I am bumping into an issue in my integration test. My code uses a system property (System.getProperty(...) ) and I am not being able to set the system property when running the integration test. Any idea on how to define system properties that are visible inside code running in integration test?

I am using Grails 3.3.1. 
Slimmed down example of integration test not seeing the system property:

```
package injecttest

import grails.testing.mixin.integration.Integration
import grails.transaction.*
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import spock.lang.Specification

@Integration
@Rollback
class C1ITSpec extends Specification {

    void "test system property readable inside test"() {
        String val = System.getProperty("var1", "ERROR")
        expect:"system variable to match value passed as '-Dvar1=OK' in command line"
            "OK" == val
    }
}
```

Comment: You could just use `System.setProperty(...)` maybe in your setup method or you can e.g. define properties in your IDE's runtime config for tests/integration tests

Answer (score 0):

A new JVM is forked to run the test, so you have to pass the command-line system properties to the test's JVM.

In Grails 4, which uses gradle, you can pass the system properties in your gradle file:

```
integrationTest.doFirst {
   systemProperties System.getProperties().subMap(["var1"])
}
```

I adapted this from the answers to this question for Grails 3:  [How to give System property to my test via Gradle and -D](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21406265/how-to-give-system-property-to-my-test-via-gradle-and-d).