# gradle java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, gradle

I am trying to run junit tests with my gradle project but regardless of the test they throw the following stacktrace

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:117)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:230)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:228)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:287)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:247)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:114)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.execute(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:57)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(JUnitTestClassProcessor.java:66)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:51)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor11.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:32)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1.processTestClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.processTestClass(TestWorker.java:108)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor10.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:146)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:128)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:404)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Parser configuration exception parsing XML from URL [file:etc/applicationContext-taxonomy.xml]; nested exception is javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException: Unable to validate using XSD: Your JAXP provider [org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl@fd06dcb] does not support XML Schema. Are you running on Java 1.4 with Apache Crimson? Upgrade to Apache Xerces (or Java 1.5) for full XSD support.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:406)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:336)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.groovy.GroovyBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(GroovyBeanDefinitionReader.java:236)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.groovy.GroovyBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(GroovyBeanDefinitionReader.java:220)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:217)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:252)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.GenericGroovyXmlContextLoader.loadBeanDefinitions(GenericGroovyXmlContextLoader.java:49)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:124)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:60)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:108)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:251)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116)
    ... 46 more
Caused by: javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException: Unable to validate using XSD: Your JAXP provider [org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl@fd06dcb] does not support XML Schema. Are you running on Java 1.4 with Apache Crimson? Upgrade to Apache Xerces (or Java 1.5) for full XSD support.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.createDocumentBuilderFactory(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:102)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:71)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadDocument(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:429)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:391)
    ... 60 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Feature 'http://apache.org/xml/features/validation/schema' is not recognized.
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl.setAttribute(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.createDocumentBuilderFactory(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:99)
    ... 63 more
```

I've seen a few suggested solutions to this but none of them seem to work.  My tests work fine when I run them in ant.  I have made sure that xerces is using the most current version I have also added the suggested

```
-Djavax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory=com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl 
-Djavax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory=com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl
```

to the JVM but nothing seems to work.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  I can provide more information upon request.

** Update **

Made the following changes --

```
test {

    jvmArgs '-Djavax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory=com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl -Djavax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory=com.sun.org.apache.xerces'
    include "test/src/java/"
    testLogging.showStandardStreams = true
    minHeapSize = "512m"
    maxHeapSize = "1024m"
}
```

but now the out put is as shown

```
:compileTestJava (Thread[Task worker for ':',5,main]) completed. Took 0.391 secs.
:compileTestGroovy (Thread[Task worker for ':',5,main]) started.

> Task :compileTestGroovy NO-SOURCE
Deleting stale output file: C:\Users\edunn\eclipse-workspace\iC\build\classes\groovy\test
file or directory 'C:\Users\edunn\eclipse-workspace\iC\src\test\groovy', not found
Skipping task ':compileTestGroovy' as it has no source files and no previous output files.

:compileTestGroovy (Thread[Task worker for ':',5,main]) completed. Took 0.001 secs.
:processTestResources (Thread[Task worker for ':',5,main]) started.

> Task :processTestResources NO-SOURCE
Deleting stale output file: C:\Users\edunn\eclipse-workspace\iC\build\resources\test
file or directory 'C:\Users\edunn\eclipse-workspace\iC\src\test\resources', not found
Skipping task ':processTestResources' as it has no source files and no previous output files.

:processTestResources (Thread[Task worker for ':',5,main]) completed. Took 0.001 secs.
:testClasses (Thread[Task worker for ':',5,main]) started.

> Task :testClasses
Skipping task ':testClasses' as it has no actions.

:testClasses (Thread[Task worker for ':',5,main]) completed. Took 0.0 secs.
:test (Thread[Task worker for ':',5,main]) started.

> Task :test
Cleaned previous output of task ':test' as it has no source files.

:test (Thread[Task worker for ':',5,main]) completed. Took 0.11 secs.

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 25s
4 actionable tasks: 4 executed
VCS Checkout Cache (C:\Users\edunn\eclipse-workspace\iC\.gradle\vcsWorkingDirs) has not been cleaned up in 1 days
```

** Update 2 **

I have made the following changes

```
test {
    systemProperty 'javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory', 'com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl'
    systemProperty 'javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory', 'com.sun.org.apache.xerces'
    include "com/compsci/ic/**"
    testLogging.showStandardStreams = true
    minHeapSize = "512m"
    maxHeapSize = "1024m"
}
```

which has gotten me further but I now get the following stacktrace

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:117)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:230)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:228)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:287)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:247)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:114)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.execute(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:57)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(JUnitTestClassProcessor.java:66)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:51)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor11.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:32)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy3.processTestClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.processTestClass(TestWorker.java:108)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor10.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:146)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:128)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:404)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'baseCorpusInitializerGaap2013' defined in URL [file:etc/applicationContext-taxonomy-usg2013.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'tableIdentCorpus' while setting bean property 'tableIdentifierTrainers'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tableIdentCorpus' defined in URL [file:etc/applicationContext-corpus.xml]: Cannot create inner bean 'com.compsci.ic.classify.corpus.PropertiesFilesMultiTrainer#37e1a955' of type [com.compsci.ic.classify.corpus.PropertiesFilesMultiTrainer] while setting bean property 'multiTrainers'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'com.compsci.ic.classify.corpus.PropertiesFilesMultiTrainer#37e1a955' defined in URL [file:etc/applicationContext-corpus.xml]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1: Could not convert argument value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [[Lorg.springframework.core.io.Resource;]: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'org.springframework.core.io.Resource[]'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve resource location pattern [classpath:data/corpus/*/*.properties]: class path resource [data/corpus/] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'com.compsci.ic.classify.corpus.PropertiesFilesMultiTrainer#37e1a955' defined in URL [file:etc/applicationContext-corpus.xml]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1: Could not convert argument value of type [java.util.ArrayList] to required type [[Ljava.net.URL;]: Failed to convert value of type 'java.util.ArrayList' to required type 'java.net.URL[]'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not retrieve URL for class path resource [ConsolidatedBalanceSheet.properties]: class path resource [ConsolidatedBalanceSheet.properties] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1492)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1237)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:552)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:759)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:128)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:60)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:108)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:251)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116)
    ... 46 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tableIdentCorpus' defined in URL [file:etc/applicationContext-corpus.xml]: Cannot create inner bean 'com.compsci.ic.classify.corpus.PropertiesFilesMultiTrainer#37e1a955' of type [com.compsci.ic.classify.corpus.PropertiesFilesMultiTrainer] while setting bean property 'multiTrainers'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'com.compsci.ic.classify.corpus.PropertiesFilesMultiTrainer#37e1a955' defined in URL [file:etc/applicationContext-corpus.xml]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1: Could not convert argument value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [[Lorg.springframework.core.io.Resource;]: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'org.springframework.core.io.Resource[]'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve resource location pattern [classpath:data/corpus/*/*.properties]: class path resource [data/corpus/] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:313)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:122)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1492)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1237)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:552)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351)
    ... 64 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'com.compsci.ic.classify.corpus.PropertiesFilesMultiTrainer#37e1a955' defined in URL [file:etc/applicationContext-corpus.xml]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1: Could not convert argument value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [[Lorg.springframework.core.io.Resource;]: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'org.springframework.core.io.Resource[]'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve resource location pattern [classpath:data/corpus/*/*.properties]: class path resource [data/corpus/] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:723)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1154)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1056)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:299)
    ... 74 more
```

I believe I am on the right track

Comment: You have to pass jvm options to also test jvm, in case you might missed it.

Comment: could you provide an example?  I am a little confused, fairly new to gradle

Answer (score 2):

According to docs, Gradle runs unit tests in different jvms (like maven surefire).

> Executes JUnit (3.8.x or 4.x) or TestNG tests. Test are always run in
>   (one or more) separate JVMs. The sample below shows various
>   configuration options.  apply plugin: 'java' // adds 'test' task

```
test {
   // enable TestNG support (default is JUnit)
   useTestNG()

   // set a system property for the test JVM(s)
   systemProperty 'some.prop', 'value'

   // explicitly include or exclude tests
   include 'org/foo/**'
   exclude 'org/boo/**'

   // show standard out and standard error of the test JVM(s) on the console
   testLogging.showStandardStreams = true

   // set heap size for the test JVM(s)
   minHeapSize = "128m"
   maxHeapSize = "512m"
```

https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/testing/Test.html

You should add your jvm args like this

```
systemProperty 'javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory', 'com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl'
```

This thread shows how to fetch arguments from gradle jvm
[How to give System property to my test via Gradle and -D](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21406265/how-to-give-system-property-to-my-test-via-gradle-and-d)

Comment: I tried doing that and the test runs with no errors but it doesn't seem to actually be testing anything.  I have done it as the following

test {
    
    jvmArgs '-Djavax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory=com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl -Djavax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory=com.sun.org.apache.xerces'
    include "test/src/java/"
    testLogging.showStandardStreams = true
    minHeapSize = "512m"
    maxHeapSize = "1024m"
}

Comment: @EdDunn did you try to add `-i` switch when calling tests. It outputs with this switch if I am not mistaken

Comment: yea, this is the output - above

Comment: @EdDunn can you try with include 'yourTestPackege/**'  instead of "test/src/java/"

Comment: I get this now in my stack trace (should add I am not a java guy either, I am devopts tasked with converting our ant builds to gradle, been a great learning experience)

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com/sun/org/apache/xerces/internal/jaxp/DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl -Djavax/xml/parsers/SAXParserFactory=com/sun/org/apache/xerces

Comment: I am edited my original post adding another updated.  See above

Comment: @EdDunn We are back to square one :). Some how it does not pick up SAXParserFactory this time. Defining jvmArgs ["arg1", "arg2"] like this will probably fix it

Comment: I think the issue is that my tests are not in the default path location so I have set them as so  -- sourceSets.test.java.srcDirs = ["test/src/java"]

If you look at the stacktrace error it is looking for -- class path resource [data/corpus/]

But data/corpus is at the base of the project not the base of the test sourcepath

Comment: @EdDunn The error log you provided with update 2 is look like to be about your bean definitions.