# How to give System property to my test via Kotlin Gradle and -D

Tags: java, gradle, kotlin, spock

When I run a test in Gradle I would like to pass some properties:

```
./gradlew test -DmyProperty=someValue
```

So in my Spock test I will use to retrieve the value:

```
def value = System.getProperty("myProperty")
```

Im using the kotlin gradle dsl. When I try and use 'tasks.test' as in this documentation: 
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_testing.html#test_filtering

'test' is not recognised in my `build.gradle.kts` file.

I'm assuming I would need to use something similar to the answer in the post below but it is not clear how it should be done in the using the gradle kotlin DSL.

[How to give System property to my test via Gradle and -D](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21406265/how-to-give-system-property-to-my-test-via-gradle-and-d)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The answers from your linked question are translatable 1:1 to the kotlin DSL. Here is a full example using junit5.

```kotlin
dependencies {
    // ...
    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.4.2")
    testImplementation(kotlin("test-junit5"))
}

tasks.withType<Test> {
    useJUnitPlatform()

    // Project property style - optional property.
    // ./gradlew test -Pcassandra.ip=xx.xx.xx.xx
    systemProperty("cassandra.ip", project.properties["cassandra.ip"])

    // Project property style - enforced property.
    // The build will fail if the project property is not defined.
    // ./gradlew test -Pcassandra.ip=xx.xx.xx.xx
    systemProperty("cassandra.ip", project.property("cassandra.ip"))

    // system property style
    // ./gradlew test -Dcassandra.ip=xx.xx.xx.xx
    systemProperty("cassandra.ip", System.getProperty("cassandra.ip"))
}
```

Answer (score 9):

This example demos three ways of passing system properties to the junit test.  Two of them specifies the system properties one at a time.  The last avoids having to forward declare each system property by taking all system properties available to the gradle runtime and passes them to the junit test harness.

```
tasks.withType<Test> {
    useJUnitPlatform()

    // set system property using a property specified in gradle
    systemProperty("a", project.properties["a"])

    // take one property that was specified when starting gradle
    systemProperty("a", System.getProperty("a"))

    // take all of the system properties specified when starting gradle
    // which avoids copying each property over one at a time
    systemProperties(System.getProperties().toMap() as Map<String,Object>)
}
```